# Code is getting SIGSEGV unless cout statements are added, then gives correct result

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++14

While I am coding in C++, I am getting a SIGSEGV error. But, when I add `cout` statements in between to know where I have gone wrong, my code is executing and giving the correct output.

Can anyone suggest how to overcome this kind of problem ?

Code if required : (code to remove loop if present in linked list):

```
void removeLoop(Node* head)
{
    Node *slow=head,*fast=head;
    int u=0;
    while(slow !=NULL and fast->next!=NULL and fast!=NULL){
        slow=slow->next;
        fast=fast->next->next;
        if(slow==fast){
            u=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(u==1){
        int k=1;
        while(fast->next!=slow){
            fast=fast->next;
            k++;
        }
        slow=head;
        fast=head;
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            fast=fast->next;
        }
        while(slow!=fast){
            slow=slow->next;
            fast=fast->next;
        }
        while(fast->next!=slow){
            fast=fast->next;
        }
        //cout<<fast->next->data<<endl;
        fast->next=NULL;
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some additional code showing (i) potential main function with the initialization of a sample linked list where the problem is occurring? (ii) your `Node` structure?

Comment: If adding an I/O statement (e.g. writing something to `cout`) causes a crashing program to stop crashing, it means that some code, somewhere in the program, is accessing memory it shouldn't.   Adding the output statement has a side-effect of changing the layout of memory used by your program (e.g. the actual address of variables, or the actual address of dynamically allocated memory) so can change what is actually at the location tromped by bad operations.   That can therefore change the visible symptoms.  It also means that the *cause* of the problem may not be in code you have shown.

Comment: got it Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at this:

```cpp
while(slow !=NULL and fast->next!=NULL and fast!=NULL){
```

Now think about what's it's going to do if `slow != NULL and fast == NULL`...

Comment: Thanks a lot    
Got it.... 
it should be `while(slow !=NULL and fast!=NULL and fast->next!=NULL) `